# improve regex to strip bracket´s content with linebreak

Tags: php, regex

i need to wipe all content inside brackets including the brackets from a string to process it for my search-engine

my regex so far is :

```
'/[\[{].*[\]}]/U'
```

this works pretty good but it doesnt work if there is a linebreak inside the brackets

here is an example ( and it took me a lot of time to narrow down to the *** linebreak...):

```
echo preg_replace('/[\[{].*[\]}]/U', ' ', strip_tags('<h1> how can i </h1>
[portfolioitem img="/fooobarbaoarbaororboabro.jpg" alt="fooobarbaoarbaororboabro"  url="fooobarbaoarbaororboabro/" imglink="Lebenslauf Â»" description="fooobarbaoarbaororboabro" headline="fooobarbaoarbaororboabro" link="Lebenslauf Â»"]

[/span][span size="6"]


<h1> wipe this away?</h1>
[portfolioitem img="fooobarbaoarbaororboabro.jpg" alt="fooobarbaoarbaororboabro" url="/fooobarbaoarbaororboabro/" imglink="foo" description="foo foo foo
bar foo foo bar foo" headline="fooo" link="Lebenslauf "]
'));
```

as you can see, there is a linebreak in the second "[portfolioitem..."
and for some reason this outputs :

```
how can i 



wipe this away?
[portfolioitem img="fooobarbaoarbaororboabro.jpg" alt="fooobarbaoarbaororboabro" url="/fooobarbaoarbaororboabro/" imglink="foo" description="foo foo foo
bar foo foo bar foo" headline="fooo" link="Lebenslauf "]
```

i dont get any further and im not regex pro enough
can someone please help me make my regex "\newline insensitive" ?!

thanks in advance for any help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `s` (DOTALL) flag in your regex to make `dot` match new lines. Try this regex:

```
/[\[{].*?[\]}]/Us
```

Comment: oh my god i believe in wonders again :D it works, thanks for the quick reply and explanation, approciate very much

Comment: what about this `\[[^]]*`

Comment: @Braj says: Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash on line